# Puma not outperforming Unicorn (Rails 5.0 app) - is this normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, amazon-ec2, unicorn, puma

Trying to make better uses of an AWS server that serves roughly 30,000 users/day. Current server:

- **AWS EC2, t3.xlarge, 4 vCPUs, 16GB memory**
- **Rails 5.0 app, Ruby 2.6.7, web server is nginx**

I was previously using Unicorn with the following config:

**- 1 master process, 4 worker processes**

I had database pool set to 5, and the app also uses Sidekiq with a concurrency of 5.

CPU usage would hover around 35-40%, and memory usage would be in the 90% range. I know Ruby processes are memory hogs, but even still memory usage seemed a *little* high.

I did all this reading about Puma being much more memory efficient than Unicorn, thus having become the default server for Rails apps. So I did the slightly painful conversion process, and a couple days later the system has stabilized. Puma config I settled on:

**- Puma 5.3.2 in cluster mode, 3 workers, threads 1 min & 5 max.**

My app's response times seem largely the same as before. But here's the thing, **memory usage is the same if not higher than Unicorn**, hovering around 90% (and climbing slowly which seems like a memory leak, but that's a different story):

[image: Here's 12 hr CPU and memory usage from New Relic]

[image: From top]

[image: From top]

I'm likely going to roll back and return to Unicorn, but I wanted to post here to see if anyone can see any possible red flags about my configuration. Happy to share more details.

Things I've tried:

- Number of Puma workers & threads, I tried with the 2 workers and 5 threads default config
- Installing Ruby 2.6.7 with jemalloc (didn't really do anything)

Comment: I wonder if u can increase the amount of puma threads? what I'm thinking is you want to see CPU utilization actually go up as much as possible right? and it's quite low

Comment: I'm glad you said that Joel I think it's strange that CPU usage is so low while mem is peaking. Seems like this website has always been like that. It's an entertainment app, ungated to readers, so mostly db reads (and memcached hits) are happening. Im not sure if 2-3gb per ruby process is normal per the traffic? Most blogs say going beyond 5 or 6 threads didn't increase performance much...

Comment: I think your new setup would be better with many concurrent requests. But your traffic isnt high enough to give puma a big advantage so you see the same response times

Comment: As for memory: the longer the process runs the higher the memory will bloat due to garbage collection not being perfect (memory fragmentation), puma wont solve it on its own

Comment: > your traffic isnt high enough to give puma a big advantage

That's so interesting. Site gets close to a million visits a month. Not being defensive at all, I know where I stand :) But that must mean all these Puma success stories on blogs are for sites that are quite large!

Comment: I could be wrong of course...this is just speculation on my part

Comment: I understand you meant workers per core, right?
The rule of thumb I use is workers = 2*cores +1 in case you have also the DB in the same server and not split, if you don't have DB you could even expand that number